# How Hiding the default android keyboard in Unreal Engine5 Mobile Project

Tags: android, android-studio, unreal

just started learning unreal engine 5. I have made an application with resizing the cube, when you click on the input fields, a keyboard appears or this field, I would like to add numbers for input by buttons, and hide this keyboard, roughly speaking remove somehow remove the event of calling this field and keyboard? Can you please tell me how I can do this?
Thank you very much in advance!

I try expecting this task in UE5, but not sucsessfuel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.